# Boolean in React useState is casted to its contrary value

Tags: reactjs, boolean, state

During creating my own sign up hook while using Firebase Auth, I've encountered a strange issue.

```js
export const useSignup = () => {
   const [error, setError] = useState(null);
   const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);
   const [isFulfilled, setIsFulfilled] = useState(false);
   const { dispatch } = useAuthContext();

   const signup = async (email, password) => {
      setError(null);
      setIsPending(true);

      try {
         const res = await projectAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email,
            password
         );

         if (!res) {
            throw new Error('Sign up has failed, please try again.');
         }

         dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: res.user });

         // Will be casted as 'true', no idea why
         setIsFulfilled(false);

         if (!isCancelled) {
            setIsPending(false);
            setError(null);
         }
      } catch (err) {
         if (!isCancelled) {
            setError(err.message);
            setIsPending(false);

            // Will be casted as 'false', also no idea why
            setIsFulfilled(true);
         }
      }
   };

   return { signup, error, isPending, isFulfilled };
};
```

After registration process will be complete, I want to set state of `isFulfilled` to `true` and pass it forward, but strangely, while debugging and logging it to console, it outputs `false`, even if I check it immediately after invoking `setIsFulfilled(true)`.

What interferes with state, so it outputs a contrary Boolean values?

Comment: Are other states being set right (isPending, isError etc.) or is it just `isFulfilled` ?

Comment: @ZaeemKhaliq only the `isFulfilled`

Answer (score 0):

remember that when setting states (ie, when using `setIsPending`) it's an asynchronous call, so don't expect them to act synchronous without their respective awaits. also, perhaps the use of `useEffect` might be useful looking at your implementation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).